# How do I fix Undefined variable using $_POST in function?

Tags: php, functions, variables

I have the following `function` but with this error: `Notice: Undefined variable: rating`. hoa can I fix it?

```
function save_comment_meta_rating($comment_id){
    if(!empty($_POST['rating']))
        $rating = sanitize_text_field($_POST['rating']);
        add_comment_meta($comment_id,'rating',$rating);

        // Then update the average rating.
        update_post_avg_rating( $comment_id );
}
add_action('comment_post','save_comment_meta_rating');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check is incorrect: right now, it tries to access `$_POST['rating']`, which might not be set, and then checks whether that value is empty. Furthermore, you should scope your `if` statement with brackets, because right now, your code will try and update the average rating even if no new rating is provided. Try:

```
function save_comment_meta_rating( $comment_id ){
    if ( ! array_key_exists( 'rating', $_POST ) || empty( $_POST['rating'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $rating = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['rating'] );
    add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', $rating );

    // Then update the average rating.
    update_post_avg_rating( $comment_id );  
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_rating' );
```

Comment: thanks but the issue is not checking, is undefined variable

Comment: Your variable being undefined might be caused by `$_POST['rating']` not being set (which should yield a notice).

Comment: yes. you were right, my friend :)